# SQL state 37000 error when trying to update record

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ajax

I'm creating a form that allows a user to create a ticket and save it to a MS SQL table, they can also search tickets via a page which has a table displaying all records in that table. Next to each record is an 'edit' button which will allow the user to the update the record. When a user clicks edit and fills in the field I get the following error.

> PHP Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'Test'., SQL state
>   37000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SMT_Request_Dev\board\Dashboard\insert.php on line
>   7" for lines 7, 8, & 9

jobUpdateNew.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       $('#insert').val("Insert");  
       $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
       var jobNumber = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{jobNumber:jobNumber},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#Update_Description').val(data.Update_Description);  
                 $('#Updated_By').val(data.Updated_By);  
                 $('#Updated_Date').val(data.Updated_Date);    
                 $('#jobNumber').val(data.jobNumber);  
                 $('#insert').val("Update");  
                 $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
            }  
       });  
  });  
  $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
       event.preventDefault();  
       if($('#Update_Description').val() == "")  
       {  
            alert("Update of issue is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#Updated_By').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Name is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#Updated_Date').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Current date is required");  
       }  

            $.ajax({  
                 url:"insert.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                 beforeSend:function(){  
                      $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                 },  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                      $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                      $('#employee_table').html(data);  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("jobNumber");  
       if(employee_id != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"select.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                      $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                 }  
            });  
       }            
  });  
 });
```

insert.php

```
<?php  
$connect = odbc_connect("Description=PCD_SQL_SERVER;DRIVER=SQL 
Server;SERVER=gbsuk0pcdspdsql","smtrfaUser","Summitdesk789"); 
if(!empty($_POST))  
{  
  $output = '';  
  $message = '';  
  $Update_Description = odbc_exec($connect, 
 $_POST["Update_Description"]);  
  $Updated_By = odbc_exec($connect, $_POST["Updated_By"]);  
  $Updated_Date = odbc_exec($connect, $_POST["Updated_Date"]);     
  if($_POST["problemDescription"] != '')  
  {  
       $query = "  
       UPDATE smtJobTracker   
       SET Update_Description='$Update_Description',   
       Updated_By='$Updated_By',   
       Updated_Date='$Updated_Date',       
       WHERE jobNumber='".$_POST["jobNumber"]."'";  
       $message = 'Data Updated';          
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $query = "  
       INSERT INTO smtJobTracker(Update_Description, Updated_By, 
 Updated_Date)  
       VALUES('$Update_Description', '$Updated_By', '$Updated_Date');  
       ";  
       $message = 'Data Inserted';  
  }  
  if(odbc_exec($connect, $query))  
  {  
       $output .= '<label class="text-success">' . $message . '</label>';  
       $select_query = "SELECT * FROM smtjobTracker ORDER BY jobNumber 
 DESC";  
       $result = odbc_exec($connect, $select_query);  
       $output .= '  
            <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <tr>  
                                <th>Job Number</th>
                                <th>Description Of Issue</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>View</th>
                 </tr>  
       ';  
       while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>' . $row["jobNumber"] . '</td>  
                      <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" 
 id="'.$row["jobNumber"] .'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /> 
</td>  
                      <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" 
 id="' . $row["jobNumber"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /> 
</td>  
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
       $output .= '</table>';  
  }  
  echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

The aim is an update of the record to include an update description, name of the updater and date updated.

Comment: So the error is clear "Could not find stored procedure 'Test'" - what further help do you want?

Comment: Thanks for replying. "Test" is what i'm manually inputting into the description field, why is it bringing this error back?

Comment: @DaleBurrell did you somewhere him calling for such a procedure ?

Comment: Because somehow somewhere you are trying to call a stored procedure called Test - as the error says. If you're not doing it then look for a trigger.

Comment: @mat1986  you are calling odbc_exec wrongly in absolute lines 8,9,10, there is no need to do that.